# Onesignal could not load iframe error

Tags: web, onesignal

I am having issues after I changed the subdomain of my app, it was working the day before but now it doesn't it shows me the message

> OneSignal: Could not load iFrame with URL
>   https://acacito.onesignal.com/webPushIframe. Please check that your
>   'subdomainName' matches that on your OneSignal Chrome platform
>   settings.

```
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];

  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(["init", {
    appId: "MyAppID", // copied correctly the UUID
    autoRegister: false, /* Set to true to automatically prompt visitors */
    subdomainName: 'acacito',
    httpPermissionRequest: {
      enable: true
    },
    notifyButton: {
        enable: true /* Set to false to hide */
    }
  }]);
</script>
```

I have been trying to make it work deleting cookies or any data related that could be stored in the browser and it doesn't work. Also reloading with Ctr+Shift+r, not sure what happens.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, this error can occur if:

- The Site URL in your onesignal.com dashboard settings does not *begin with* the same URL you're using to access your site.

  For example, if your dashboard platform setting's Site URL is `http://my-site.com`, you have to access your site beginning with the URL `http://my-site.com`. You can access `http://my-site.com/page1`, and you can access `http://my-site.com/folder/page2`, but you have to begin with `http://my-site.com`. Technically, the Site URL is the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) your OneSignal configuration is allowed to run under, and OneSignal doesn't allow any other site origin from initializing OneSignal with the same subdomain.

  For more complicated cases:

  - If you're developing locally on `http://localhost:8181`, your Site URL should also be `http://localhost:8181` (with the port number).
  - If you have an alias defined in your `hosts` file, you still have to use the origin specified in your Site URL. The OneSignal web SDK looks at what's on the address bar and compares it to what's in the Site URL textbox.
- The value for `subdomainName` (in this case `acacito`) does not match the value you chose in your onesignal.com dashboard settings for Chrome web push.

  Just be sure to use the same value.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using other platform

Comment: how set localhost to OneSignal for test on develop.I cannot do this. any documention exist, please help.